# Python recursion timings in return statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trying to time recursions of factorials and I cannot find a way around printing every factorial in each recursion step. Now I have tried printing it just in the return statement which would solve my problem, but that just ended up in a mess of wall of text with timings being fragmented.

EDIT: I should mention that I am trying to get the cumulative timings of the whole process and not fragmented results like I have below with the print statement.

I tried something like:

```
return (str(n) + '! = ' + (str(FactResult)) +  
                   ' - Runtime = %.9f seconds' % (end-start))
```

But here is what I have below as of now.

```
import time
def factorial(n):
"""Factorial function that uses recursion and returns factorial of
number given."""
start = time.clock()
if n < 1:
    return 1
else:
    FactResult = n * factorial(n - 1)
    end = time.clock()
    print(str(n) + '! - Runtime = %.9f seconds' % (end-start))
    return FactResult
```

Comment: It looks like the indentation is messed up. You obviously can't use the first return since that's a string, unless you want to parse the value out of it every time.

Comment: Just as a note: recursion is *not* the fastest implementation of this.

Comment: What is not clear to me though is what times are you trying to print? How long it takes for each step to complete? Or do you want a cumulative time?

Comment: maybe look into the timeit or profile modules ...

Comment: I realize recursion isn't the best solution for this method, but it is required for this part of an assignment.


Also I am trying to get the cumulative timing of the whole process.

Comment: Then why not just do something like `start = time.clock(); factorial(n); print time.clock() - start`? Also, see [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work fine after fixing the indentation and minor (cosmetic) changes:

```
import time

def factorial(n):
    """Factorial function that uses recursion and returns factorial of number given."""

    start = time.clock()
    if n < 1:
        return 1
    else:
        FactResult = n * factorial(n - 1)
        end = time.clock()
        print(str(n) + '! =', FactResult, '- Runtime = %.9f seconds' % (end-start))
        return FactResult

factorial(10)
```

It prints for me... without printing the result value:

```
c:\tmp\___python\BobDunakey\so12828669>py a.py
1! - Runtime = 0.000001440 seconds
2! - Runtime = 0.000288474 seconds
3! - Runtime = 0.000484790 seconds
4! - Runtime = 0.000690225 seconds
5! - Runtime = 0.000895181 seconds
6! - Runtime = 0.001097736 seconds
7! - Runtime = 0.001294052 seconds
8! - Runtime = 0.001487008 seconds
9! - Runtime = 0.001683804 seconds
10! - Runtime = 0.001884920 seconds
```

... and with printing the value:

```
c:\tmp\___python\BobDunakey\so12828669>py a.py
1! = 1 - Runtime = 0.000001440 seconds
2! = 2 - Runtime = 0.001313252 seconds
3! = 6 - Runtime = 0.002450827 seconds
4! = 24 - Runtime = 0.003409847 seconds
5! = 120 - Runtime = 0.004300708 seconds
6! = 720 - Runtime = 0.005694598 seconds
7! = 5040 - Runtime = 0.006678577 seconds
8! = 40320 - Runtime = 0.007579038 seconds
9! = 362880 - Runtime = 0.008463659 seconds
10! = 3628800 - Runtime = 0.009994826 seconds
```

**EDIT**

For the cumulative timing, you have to measure outside the call. Otherwise you are not able to capture the start time. It is also more natural:

```
import time

def factorial(n):
    """Factorial function that uses recursion and returns factorial of number given."""

    if n < 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n - 1)


n = 10

start = time.clock()
result = factorial(n)
end = time.clock()

print(str(n) + '! =', result, '- Runtime = %.9f seconds' % (end-start))
```

It prints:

```
c:\tmp\___python\BobDunakey\so12828669>py a.py
10! = 3628800 - Runtime = 0.000007200 seconds
```

Comment: +1 _Always_ divide I/O from the logic of your programs. Messing them up makes the code harder to reuse, to maintain _and_ it is _slower_, and that it can be a lot slower(see the results in this answer from 0.0099 to 0.0000072 for 10!...).

Answer (score 0):

Move the "end = time.clock()" and the print statement right before the "return 1" in the block  that catches n<1. This is the last execution at the biggest depth of the recursion stack, so all you will miss is the backing up out of it. To get the most proper result, you should follow the suggestion of NullUserException and time outside the recursion method.